# A good way to check if the payment form was left off in between

Tags: api, paypal

We use PayPal to accept donations on our website. The problem we're facing is usually this happens that a user clicks on the pay button on our website but then for some reason drops from PayPal.

Is there a way through the PayPal API we could check that the user for some reason left off the transaction or maybe his transaction was denied.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not; keep track of that drop off yourself if they don't come back or you don't get a resulting transaction.

If you are *not* using an API to accept the donations, then to be notified of resulting transactions you can [use Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/). A parameter you can use for reconciliation is `custom`, which can be set at the moment the user clicks 'Pay' and you redirect them to PayPal.

(But if you *are* using an API, then the API is your notification already)